# Hibernate Exception - could not resolve property:

Tags: hibernate

I am trying to retrieve an object and its children. The request comes up with an exception.

Models - The staff class is a self reference class where the checker with a checker_id is also a staff. And also both the staff and checker has a one to many relationship with the module model.

```
   public class Staff implements Serializable, 
  @Id
  @Column(name = "staff_id")
  private String staffId;

  @ManyToOne(cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
  @JoinColumn(name="checker_id")
  private Staff checker;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy="checker", orphanRemoval=true, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  private Set<Staff> setters = new HashSet<Staff>();

  @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="setter")
  private Set<Module> sModule = new HashSet<Module>();

  @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="checker")
  private Set<Module> cModule = new HashSet<Module>(); 

 //getters and setters}
```

Module model

```
  public class Module implements Serializable{

  @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY) 
 @JoinColumn(name="staff_id", insertable=false, updatable=false)
 private Staff setter;

 @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY) 
 @JoinColumn(name="checker_id", insertable=false, updatable=false)
 private Staff checker; 

 //getters and setters }
```

DAO code

```
  @Transactional
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public Staff getWithModules(String staffId){

    //Retrieve Staff
    Criteria crit = getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Staff.class);
    crit.add(Restrictions.eq("staffId", staffId));
    Staff staff = get(crit);

    //Retrieve the modules for the staff
    crit = getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Module.class);
    crit.add(Restrictions.eq("Staff.staffId", staffId));
    crit.add(Restrictions.isNull("checkerId"));
    crit.addOrder(Order.asc("moduleId"));
    Set<Module> sModule = new LinkedHashSet<Module>(crit.list());
    staff.setsModule(sModule);  
    //Set<Module> modules = new LinkedHashSet<Module>(crit.list());
    //staff.setModules(modules);
    return staff;
}
```

When I try to get any staff id and along with it the modules attached to it. I get this error in the stacktrace:

```
    org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: Staff of: com.project.professional.model.Module
org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractPropertyMapping.propertyException(AbstractPropertyMapping.java:83)
org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractPropertyMapping.toType(AbstractPropertyMapping.java:77)
org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.getSubclassPropertyTableNumber(AbstractEntityPersister.java:1945)
org.hibernate.persister.entity.BasicEntityPropertyMapping.toColumns(BasicEntityPropertyMapping.java:61)
org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.toColumns(AbstractEntityPersister.java:1920)
org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaQueryTranslator.getColumns(CriteriaQueryTranslator.java:523)
org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaQueryTranslator.findColumns(CriteriaQueryTranslator.java:538)
org.hibernate.criterion.SimpleExpression.toSqlString(SimpleExpression.java:66)
org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaQueryTranslator.getWhereCondition(CriteriaQueryTranslator.java:419)
org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaJoinWalker.<init>(CriteriaJoinWalker.java:123)
org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaJoinWalker.<init>(CriteriaJoinWalker.java:92)
org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaLoader.<init>(CriteriaLoader.java:95)
org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1602)
org.hibernate.internal.CriteriaImpl.list(CriteriaImpl.java:374)
com.project.professional.dao.StaffDAO.getWithModules(StaffDAO.java:60)
com.project.professional.dao.StaffDAO$$FastClassByCGLIB$$d033d033.invoke(<generated>)
org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:698)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:631)
com.project.professional.dao.StaffDAO$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$58379429.getWithModules(<generated>)
com.project.professional.service.StaffServiceImpl.getWithModules(StaffServiceImpl.java:54)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
$Proxy46.getWithModules(Unknown Source)
com.project.professional.controller.StaffController.showStaffModules(StaffController.java:83)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:219)
org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:746)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:687)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:915)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:811)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:796)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:183)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
```

I would appreciate knowing what the problem is.

Comment: is the Staff class mentioned in your hibernate.cfg.xml file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
crit = getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Module.class);
crit.add(Restrictions.eq("Staff.staffId", staffId));
```

This means that you're telling Hibernate that the property `id` of the property `Staff` of the entity `Module` should be equal to `staffId`. But there is no `Staff` property in `Module`, as the exception message rightly says. `Module` has a property named `setter`, and another one named `checker`.

Comment: Thank you. That was the problem. I changed the property to setter.

Answer (score 0):

I had this similar error popping up. Could not resolve property: property name of: BO name. Before I had refactored the same property name and it's getters and setters correctly. Yet the error reoccured. So I deleted the getter and setter and regenerated it through "Generate getters and setters" option . The issue resolved. It seemed that hibernate mapping was not able to read the getter from the refactored code. P.S.  Thought of sharing this as it may be helpful to anybody who has a similar error message .